# What's a good way to find and mark paragraphs or other HTML tags that contain a string, with PHP?

Tags: php, wordpress

Context: WordPress development sites with lorem ipsum in random places. Would like to present these content areas in red, so they're not missed and they're prominent during review.

Example:

```
<p>This is real content and has no dummy words.</p>
<p>This has words like lorem and ipsum. It should be highlighted.</p>
```

Desired end result:

```
<p>This is real content and has no dummy words.</p>
<p style="color:red">This has words like lorem and ipsum. It should be highlighted.</p>
```

Thank you!

Comment: Look into [DOMDocument](http://php.net/manual/en/class.domdocument.php)

Comment: Why don't you use javascript or jQuery for that? You can simply run a command $( "div:contains('lorem')" ).css( "color", "red" ); on document load and color it red..

Comment: @NickSurmanidze Yes, that's how I did it for the time being. I just wanted to know how to approach similar situations in the future. I'm glad I asked the question because I learned about DOMDocument!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here we go again... [Don't use a regex to parse html](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1732454/797495)! Use an html parser like [DOMDocument](http://php.net/manual/fr/class.domdocument.php), here's what you need:

```
<?php
//DEBUG START - Remove on production mode
error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('display_errors', '1');
//DEBUG END
$html = <<< EOF
<p>This is real content and has no dummy words.</p>
<p>This has words like lorem and ipsum. It should be highlighted.</p>
EOF;

$dom = new DOMDocument(); //create new DOMDocument
$dom->loadHTML($html); // load the $html in the new DOMDocument
$xpath = new DOMXPath($dom); // create a new DOMXPath
// loop all <p> tags on the html
foreach($xpath->query("//p") as $paragraph ){ //
        //if paragraph text contains lorem ipsum
        if(preg_match('/lorem|ipsum/im', $paragraph->textContent)){
        //add attribute style="color:red"
        $paragraph->setAttribute("style", "color:red");
        }
}
//save the new html with the modifications above
$html =  $dom->saveHTML();
echo $html;
```

---

**Output:**

```
<p>This is real content and has no dummy words.</p>
<p style="color:red">This has words like lorem and ipsum. It should be highlighted.</p>
```

---

[Live Demo](http://ideone.com/YVnSpF)

---

Note:

`PHP >= 5.2.6`, will automatically add `<html><body>` and `<!DOCTYPE>` tags to the document if they are missing, without asking whether you want them, Here's a simple hack to remove them:

```
$html = preg_replace('/^<!DOCTYPE.+?>/', '', str_replace( array('<html>', '</html>', '<body>', '</body>'), array('', '', '', ''), $dom->saveHTML()));
echo $html;
```

---

---

If you **really need** a regex use [preg_replace](http://php.net/manual/fr/function.preg-replace.php) with [positive lookahead](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html) for `lorem|ipsum` , i.e:

```
$html = preg_replace('%<p>(?=.*lorem|ipsum.*)(.*?)</p>%im', '<p style="color:red">$1</p>', $html);
```

---

**Regex Explanation:**

```
<p>(?=.*lorem|ipsum.*)(.*?)</p>

Options: Case insensitive; Exact spacing; Dot doesn’t match line breaks; ^$ match at line breaks; Greedy quantifiers; Regex syntax only

Match the character string “<p>” literally (case insensitive) «<p>»
Assert that the regex below can be matched, starting at this position (positive lookahead) «(?=.*lorem|ipsum.*)»
   Match this alternative (attempting the next alternative only if this one fails) «.*lorem»
      Match any single character that is NOT a line break character (line feed) «.*»
         Between zero and unlimited times, as many times as possible, giving back as needed (greedy) «*»
      Match the character string “lorem” literally (case insensitive) «lorem»
   Or match this alternative (the entire group fails if this one fails to match) «ipsum.*»
      Match the character string “ipsum” literally (case insensitive) «ipsum»
      Match any single character that is NOT a line break character (line feed) «.*»
         Between zero and unlimited times, as many times as possible, giving back as needed (greedy) «*»
Match the regex below and capture its match into backreference number 1 «(.*?)»
   Match any single character that is NOT a line break character (line feed) «.*?»
      Between zero and unlimited times, as few times as possible, expanding as needed (lazy) «*?»
Match the character string “</p>” literally (case insensitive) «</p>»

<p style="color:red">$1</p>

Insert the character string “<p style="color:red">” literally «<p style="color:red">»
Insert the text that was last matched by capturing group number 1 «$1»
Insert the character string “</p>” literally «</p>»
```

Comment: Thank you @PedroLobito! I learned about DOMDocument, which is pretty exciting!

Comment: You're Welcome, I'm glad it worked out for you! I love regexes but the way to got with `html`parsing  is `DOMDocument`

Answer (score -1):

If you don't have any complicated needs, this could fit for you:

```
$all_paragraphs = "<p>This is real content and has no dummy text.</p>
<p>This has words like lorem and ipsum. It should be highlighted.</p>";

$match = "lorem and ipsum";
$highlighted = preg_replace("/<p>(.*?){$match}(.*?)<\/p>/", "<p style='color: red'>$1$match$2</p>", $all_paragraphs);
//echo $highlighted;
```

Comment: Thanks, but this only works for paragraphs specifically.

Comment: Yes, as it said paragraphs in your question title. Regexes would work fine and faster than DOM if you have limited need as I said in the first line.